# Lost: a country’s journey

Tags: knowledge, steganography, geography

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [A-Countries-Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+puzzle+belongs+to+the+puzzle+series%3A+A+Countries+Journey%22+).
This is part 1.

---

You wake up in a corner.
It’s cold here.

You head down a dark path. There’s weird graffiti on the walls. You can see different pieces. Unfortunately, you only remember the words.

Lego er det bedste! - Otto!

Men ahamiyatsiz emasman! - Ron

តើអ្នកធ្ងន់ធ្ងរទេ រ៉ន? ប្រទេសកម្ពុជារស់នៅបានយូរ! - លន់នី

Tehnoloogia! Arvutid! Venemaa häkkimine! Litvaga! - Anders

Then some others, where only the names are visible.

เนีย! Diego! ओमांशु!

A wild country appears, and asks you what country he is from.

“But do not worry, my friend! The wall’s always there for you to watch, waiting for entrance into the next building, where the LNU is!”

Okay, fine. Watching the walls, you realize something important.
You rush back to the country, and tell him who he is.
He says, YES! Come, come, little one, wonders await you!

Comment: This one is slightly longer, and sadly NOT spelling related. Or is it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure, but should I answer:

> This is Illyria, lady?

Because

> The acrostic of the language names of the messages (Danish, Uzbek, Khmer, Estonian). Spell out DUKE and the names make the acrostic ORLANDO. There's a character is Twelfth Night of Duke Orsino and also the famous opening line of Act I Scene 2  spoken by Viola "What country, friends, is this?" with the response as above.

Comment: That's actually INCREDIBLE. Alas, poor me! I distracted myself and meant to put ORLEANS. You still get the tick, though, for finding me out.

Comment: But more importantly: France appears before you, laughing in that strange manner: "HON HON HON, messieur, oui oui!" France tells you that he assumed the disguise to be the gatekeeper of the LNU. "Now, now, petit one, go and see him! He won't bite! Hon hON!" You step forward, into the LNU's office...