# Found: a country's testing

Tags: knowledge

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [A-Countries-Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+puzzle+belongs+to+the+puzzle+series%3A+A+Countries+Journey%22+).
This is part 2.

---

You've been found by the LNU, whoever he is.

He gives you what looks like a standardized test, along with instructions:

> *This paper is worthless. The LNU is the answer. BEHOLD:*
>
> *COVID-19 recovery: youth taking action for a sustainable future*
>
> *Yemen: New Houthi commitment 'encouraging step' to protecting children*
>
> *Embracing beekeeping in the Gambia's dryland forests*
>
> ...
>
> *Look upon all I have done. I am a necessity, yet thee think I am worthless. BEHOLD MY POWER!*

Wow, he seems busy. Maybe best not to disturb him until you have his name.

An intercom comes on, and the LNU gives a final warning: "my favorite color is blue, and *be good, child, alright*?"

Fine. You'll be better.

**Who is the LNU?**

PS: The answer to the last question in the series was:

> France masquerading as Illyria, the country in a Shakespearean play.

PSS: Outside links **ARE VERY IMPORTANT** to this puzzle series in general.

HINT ONE:

> Illyria comes up to you. "Quoi? This was supposed to be the easiest parte de your testing! No matter, maybe OTAN might help toi. America has SOME logique..."

HINT TWO:

> Illyria, AKA France, is one of the few to call him NU or LNU.

Comment: This is supposed to be a sequel to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115820/lost-a-country-s-journey

Comment: [Links](https://www.ohchr.org/en/statements-and-speeches/2022/04/covid-19-recovery-youth-taking-action-sustainable-future) [Not](https://news.un.org/en/story/2022/04/1116402) [Unrelevant](https://www.fao.org/fao-stories/article/en/c/1500032/).

Comment: Yes... yes... 'tis all working out... now just put it together... That third one is the wrong link, though, but why should I be telling you that? (I capitalized for emphasis).

Comment: But seriously, I need to add that...

Comment: UNRELATEDLY, at what points in a puzzle’s existence should I post hints?

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2800/5373

Comment: Thanks. In exchange, I offer something: “Links Not Unrelevant” is totally correct, they are relevant, but in what way? The series doesn’t end here, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LNU might just be

> The United Nations (*Les Nations Unies*, even though in French it is called ONU, standing for *Organisation des Nations Unies*)

How to get there:

> The paper describes three situations, found by @Rand to be actions undertaken by the United Nations. A lot of people seem to think that the UN doesn't do much (especially given [the current context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War))
>  The UN's logo is blue, which explains the favorite color.
>  As for the *be good child* I don't have it quite yet, maybe it's about the UN's actions towards helping children

Comment: Yessir yessir yessir,, "be good child" was just a random undertale reference