# the television: a country's finale

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cipher, cryptic-clues, metapuzzles

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [A-Countries-Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+puzzle+belongs+to+the+puzzle+series%3A+A+Countries+Journey%22)
This is part 3.

New country! Welcome to the UN! Here is your task for today:

**Germany's Cryptics Factory: where the cryptics are always cryptic!**

> Here are some untested cryptics, just for you!
>
> SrDrt
>
> 1. SQDDR falling (6)
> 2. France and Germany affirm magic (5)
> 3. He, Don, has store items (5)
> 4. Puerile Yoda’s Japanese neighbor (4)
> 5. At night, a British official (2)

**China's Confusion Puzzles App: we have monies!**

> tnrywstrisbacnsrkbyhiruccrqcupejxtstnntsxzlrieob"ywlbnxwnyxsstnrtu,ailufdowmhomjrpauauhhu".

**Rome's Riddling Cards: Classical Riddles for a more... *civilized* age.**

> The third is a medal,
>
> for a long forgotten lover,
>
> of the languages of yore, (ah, so romantic),
>
> its land is like no other.
>
> The medal is shiny,
>
> common for rings, (ah, so much romance!),
>
> when he asks what it’s made of,
>
> What do they sing?

**Le finale en FRANCE! (Illyria, honhonhonhon!)**

> 11010101, as programming.
> Waicv. Eqn bux, bpl ugzggh of ubhmzzx/waolwqtjnbtegkgmiksjhagkvx. Exil hev.

**What does the UN want you to get?**

*Hint One, from a Germany*

> Ach! Hallo, klein one! SrDrT jostles fur position, while SQDDR is already high above. Affirming magic has to do with planks, and the Japanese neighbor doesn’t really exist, mein kleine Freund(or Freundin, Ich kann’t forget…).

*Hint Two, from the UN*

> Rotate the first, translate the second, be wary of the third, watch the fourth, and combine the fifth. Of the first, of course. The third main is own-solvable, of course! But you need the others to understand France.

*Hint Three, from another Germany*

> Hmmm... maybe these were too hard... Don sounds like he's a model. And remember, rotate the first one only its number! As for the third puzzle, the medal is a metal. The lover is a country, but its language is far away from its roots.

*Hint Four, from a Switzerland jeweler*

> From what I hear, the third was popular in the 1960's and such. By the way, he isn't very big and he's young.

*Hint Five, from inside you*

> You feel the friend is somewhat imaginary, that  third country seems lonely…

*Hint Six, from the third*

> Sometimes, people think I have a monster inside of me. Other times, I'm just an irrelevant communist. But I'm not.

*Hint Seven (i think i made this too hard)*

> Didn't know that it was FRENCH that diverged most from its roots in LANGUAGE, but it's in places, @WoomyRogue!

*Hint Eight, from Mater Romae*

> It's a special metal. 78/799, but only for May the Fourth be with you.

*BIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIG HINTEH BOI, from Germany*

> SrDrT is location in clues into numbers into the solutions. SQDDR falling is above TREES, so... Don dons things, and he wears solutions. Puerile is to a baby is Yoda is to...

*VERY BIG HINT, QUICKLY, FIVE HOURS REMAIN!*

> China is a visionary, France needs all three keys, translate platinum, and I gave you the big hint about Germany's. Hurry! Hurry! The hour is nigh!

*Hint 1011*

> I came through space and time to say: Switzerland likes SQDDR, He, don, dons store items and wears _____. Puerile Yoda is a baby, his neighbor is in the interblags (see xkcd) and, to some, has drip.

*PROGRESS THUS FAR*

> @xyldke has solved Rome's Riddling Cards! Now y'all need to solve Germany's Cryptics Factory to solve China's.

Comment: PARTIAL ANSWERS ARE ACCEPTABLE

Comment: A lot of thought went into this. Problem is I'm not clear on what I'm supposed to do. Could you elaborate on the type of puzzle, and make the description more clear?

Comment: You solve each minipuzzle as you go down, first Germany's, then China's, etc. the goal is to finish all of them and use them to solve the final part.

Comment: Is this part 2 or 3? [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115820/lost-a-country-s-journey), [part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115829/found-a-countrys-testing). So is this part 3?

Comment: Yeah. The other parts aren’t necessary though.

Comment: I *feel* like a knowledge tag might be missing

Comment: yeah it prob is ill add it.

Comment: @someoneinexistence Are all the country puzzles independent or do you need the answer to solve a country?

Comment: The first and third are independent, and the rest are cryptography. Germany needs to be solved in order to solve China's and then France's.

Comment: @someoneinexistence so we cant solve the rest until we solve Germany?

Comment: Nope. I feel like that was a flaw in my design. But I thought Germany would be easy (dying inside)

Comment: You can always add more hints...

Answer (score 4):

This is incomplete, I'll add more if I figure these out, but hopefully this might help someone else!

**Germany's Cryptics Factory**

> 1. Foiled again...
>
>  2. **OUIJA** (Affirm = Okay/Yes, in both French and German, OUI + JA)
>  The hint of "planks" refers to the [Oujia board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouija)
>
>  3.  Still working on this one...
>
>  4.  Removed past guess due to being incorrect.
>
>  5. Double definition of **PM** ("At night" and abbreviation of [Prime Minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom))

**Rome's Riddling Cards**
*Please see xyldke's solution!*

Comment: Wow! Second and fifth are correct, but the fourth, like I said, doesn't exist in the real world.

Comment: French Gold is not Rome's answer. It's a different metal, and a different land. Close though!

Comment: Number 1(1) is incorrect, but think of where SQDDR is in relation to trees, and what that could mean. Also, SrDrT is INCREDIBLY important to the final answer.

Comment: @someoneinexistence Is the country rot13(Tnhy, nf va Tnyyvhz naq gur ertvba bs Senapr?)?

Comment: Pyrire, nynf, tnyyvhz vfa'g hfnoyr va evatf. Vg'f gjb hapbaarpgrq pbhagevrf naq zrgnyf.

Comment: *THINKING NOISES* I believe in you! @xyldke is REALLY close to 3's solution, so why not work on Germany's Cryptics Factory? (yes this is sort of a hitn for yall)

Comment: It's ABOVE THE TREES but it starts with an A. Hint Four's country would be used to it.

Comment: @someoneinexistence Possible #3 rot13(EUVAR vf n evire gung tbrf guebhtu Senapr naq Treznal.) It also has 5 letters

Comment: "Ur, Qba, jrnef fgber vgrzf" vf fhccbfrq gb ersrerapr uvz QBAAVAT _ _ _ _ _. V oryvrir va l'nyy! @VarunW.

Answer (score 3):

See [WoomyRogue's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115896/78836) for **Germany's Cryptics Factory**

This is a partial answer for **Rome's Riddling Cards**

> We're looking for a country/land/administrative region with the following criteria:
>
>
>  1. Romance language
>
>  2. Sounds like a shiny metal is in it's name
>
>  3. Is in Europe (european amnesia by reindeer), see also someoneinexistence's comment.
>
>  4. Not actually a real country
>
>  5. Is thought to contain a monster
>
>  6. Formerly communist
>
>
>  The country is **Romania**, but the shiny metal remains unknown. Also the friend is not known yet, as Romania is very real.
>
>  Based on hint 8, the metal might be **Platinum** (it's number 78 in the periodic table) and it contains the string "latin" which is the origin of the romance languages. I'm unsure about other connections,though.
>
>  Romanian is a romance language with slavic influences (and also often forgotten among the romance languages). It is also geographically separated from the other romance languages by slavic languages in the Balkans.
>
>   Romania used to be communist (but outside the Warsaw pact and thus internationally insignificant) and lies in Europe.
>
>  Platinum is also sometimes considered to be the medal above Gold.

Solution

> The Romanian for Platinum is **platină**.

Comment: I feel sort of proud of myself, for having thwarted two solvers. The real country sounds like it's in its name.

Comment: they would sing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: If the ID starts with dQw4, I'm not watching the video :D The only problem is: I don't know if it's just a joke or if there's a hint in there somewhere...

Comment: there isnt a hint. european amnesia by a reindeer is a sorta hint, though

Comment: the friend IS a country that doesn't exist, buddy.

Comment: ROMANIA IS CORRECT! However, it isn't silver. Silver's been used for aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaages. It's something much more common.

Comment: There's another thing, with European Amnesia by a Reindeer, European for Romania, Amnesia for a song, and Reindeer for the singer, it was a really weird reference to Romania's Eurovision entry last year. IDK why that would help.

Comment: YES! ROMANIA AND PLATINUM! USE THE LANGUAGE, UNLOCK THE THIRD KEY! GO, MAN/WOMAN/IDK!